# how to get and store second last order by datetime element in json data in c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am receiving multiple records when I expect one record which is the second to last record of json data.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might be doing incorrectly?

Sample data:

```
{  
   "timestamp":"2017-03-17T17:33:09.156Z",
   "dataFrame":"VGVtcDoyOC43MA==",
   "fcnt":318,
   "port":2,
   "rssi":-107,
   "snr":0.8,
   "sf_used":7,
   "id":1489771989156,
   "decrypted":true
},
{  
   "timestamp":"2017-03-17T17:33:16.614Z",
   "dataFrame":"SHVtOjQzLjA0",
   "fcnt":319,
   "port":2,
   "rssi":-108,
   "snr":2.8,
   "sf_used":7,
   "id":1489771996614,
   "decrypted":true
}
```

Code:

```
 public ActionResult pir()
        {
            List<PIRDetailsViewModel> model = new List<PIRDetailsViewModel>();
            model.AddRange(getPirDetails("0000acfffe588041"));
            model = model.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedTime).ToList();
            return View(model);

        }

 private List<PIRDetailsViewModel> getPirDetails(string deviceID)
        {
            List<PIRDetailsViewModel> model = new List<PIRDetailsViewModel>();

            try
            {
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https:example.com");
                req.Method = "GET";
                req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + "password==";
                HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                var encoding = resp.CharacterSet == "" ? Encoding.UTF8 : Encoding.GetEncoding(resp.CharacterSet);
                using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
                    var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    List<PIRDetail> Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<PIRDetail>>(responseString);

                    foreach (var item in Pirs)
                    {
                        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(item.dataFrame.ToString());
                        PIRDetailsViewModel binModel = new PIRDetailsViewModel();
                        binModel.deviceid = deviceID;
                        binModel.status = Convert.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Substring(4));                        
                        binModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(item.timestamp, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
                        model.Add(binModel);    
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
            }

            return model;
        }
```

The above code only returns multiple records, but I am trying to get the second to last record that is being returned each time this code is ran.

Comment: So to clarify, you need to get the first record where "dataFrame" = "VGVtcDoyOC43MA=="?

Comment: `catch (Exception Ex)`{} don't do that: you are hiding your software problems. If you don't have any meaningful way to handle the exception, don't catch it

Comment: i have some hundred elements. in that last but one, last -1 element.that is just a sample data "VGVtcDoyOC43MA==" which record i need.

Comment: it will always be 2nd to last? Or does it need to handle if it's 3rd (nth) from last sometimes?

Comment: no it will be always second last only order by descending time

Comment: last record contains humidity and second last contains temp. and latest will be in the last of the json data.now i need to get temp value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm rewriting.  Based on comments, I think you want something more like below (loop not necessary):

```
List<PIRDetail> Pirs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<PIRDetail>>(responseString);
var item = Pirs[Pirs.Count -2];

byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(item.dataFrame.ToString());
PIRDetailsViewModel binModel = new PIRDetailsViewModel();
binModel.deviceid = deviceID;
binModel.status = Convert.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Substring(4));                        
binModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(item.timestamp, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
model.Add(binModel);
```

Comment: VGVtcDoyOC43MA== it means Temp:28.70, as ur answer where ever we get this value we are storing. but my requirement is last record where it contains "VGVtcDo". because real time temp value changes.

Comment: This code still gives you the correct record.  You are looking for a property called dataFrame.  So, you just grab it...  I'll modify it.

Comment: Modified, I think if I understand you correctly that's what you want.  If not, let me know.  I think I understand what you're going for but may be wrong.

Comment: I changed it to where everything that's dependent on data is in the If.  Question... Are you looping through all of these records only to find the 2nd to last one?  If so, you don't need a loop at all.  You can just index it...  Basically, if you are going to move all of that binModel code into the if... just get rid of the loop and take Pirs[Count - 2].[Variables]

Comment: yes i just want 2nd to last one only.do i need to remove foreach loop. what will be efficient code , can u edit my code

Comment: I think we got you there.  Let me know if that's not what you need, but based on above, I don't think the loop is efficient at all... Not if it's always 2nd to last. (also, if you're ordering descending, it may need to just be "var item = Pirs[2];" .... It depends on which direction it's 2nd to last.  That'll be up to you to fix though :)

Comment: what will be there in place of item.?

Comment: It's there, look again.